# Get the amount of the bill in the class method

Tags: php, laravel

Sorry for my English.

I want to make a record that would be deduced me the sum of all my orders, that is, folded string of orders and drew grouped by orders.

I have created a model "Sale", which comprises method AmountOrder

```
public function AmountOrder()
    {

        $AmountOrder = DB::table('goods')
            ->join('sale_lines', 'sale_lines.good_id', '=', 'goods.id')
            ->where('sale_id', $this->id)
            ->select(DB::raw('SUM(price*quantity) as total_sales'))
            ->value('total_sales');

        return $AmountOrder;

    }
```

and to deduce the code like this

```
@foreach ($sales as $sale)
    <tr>
        <td class="table-text"><div>{{ $sale->id }}</div></td>

        <td>
            {{ $sale->client->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$sale->date}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$sale->AmountOrder($sale)}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$sale->debt($sale)}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{$sale->date_of_issue}}
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

But the problem is that the query is performed on each line. I'm new to Laravel, but thought maybe you can solve this problem somehow more beautiful?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your method does not have a parameter so `$sale->AmountOrder($sale)` should be `$sale->AmountOrder()`

Comment: Have you given correct relationship between your models Sale and Good?

Comment: You say that I have spelled out in the migration ore in my model?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably talking about the [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations).

From the docs:

> When accessing Eloquent relationships as properties, the relationship data is "lazy loaded". This means the relationship data is not actually loaded until you first access the property. However, Eloquent can "eager load" relationships at the time you query the parent model. Eager loading alleviates the N + 1 query problem.

However, you will be not able to use the Eager Loading now, with this code in the `AmountOrder` method.

A simple google search, also, led me to [this example of Eager Loading](http://laravel.io/forum/01-13-2015-eager-loading-with-aggregate-functionsrelations) with aggregate functions/relationships.

It will be probably a good start to think and implement your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have not yet received, but now I know which way to go

Comment: Glad I helped @Grozwalker

Answer (score 0):

you have wrong in your select :

```
    $AmountOrder = DB::table('goods')
        ->join('sale_lines', 'sale_lines.good_id', '=', 'goods.id')
        ->where('sale_id', $this->id)
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(sale_lines.price*sale_lines.quantity) as total_sales'))
        ->value('total_sales');
```

Comment: Maybe my version of the query is not quite correct, but it also worked. But thank you for your note, I rewrite request

Answer (score 0):

My relationship

```
class Sale extends Model
{
    //Получаем товар в этой продаже
    public function good()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Good');
    }
}


class Good extends Model
{
    //В каких закупках был этот товар
    public function purchases()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase');
    }

    //Продажи с этим товаром
    public function sales()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Sale');
    }
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

In my model i create method

```
public function AmountOrderRelation()
{

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Good')
        ->selectRaw('sum(price) as aggregate, id')
        ->groupBy('id');
}
```

In controller

```
$new_sales = Sale::with('AmountOrderRelation')->get();


@foreach ($new_sales as $sale)
                <tr>
                    <td class="table-text"><div>{{ $sale->id }}</div></td>

                    <td>
                        {{ $sale->AmountOrderRelation }}
                    </td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

But my relations is null. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```
public function AmountOrder()
{

    return $this->HasOne('App\SaleLines')
        ->join('goods', 'sale_lines.good_id', '=', 'goods.id')
        ->selectRaw(DB::raw('SUM(price*quantity) as aggregate, sale_id'))
        ->groupBy('sale_id');
}

public function getAmountOrderAttribute()
{
    // if relation is not loaded already, let's do it first
    if ( ! array_key_exists('AmountOrder', $this->relations))
        $this->load('AmountOrder');

    $related = $this->getRelation('AmountOrder');

    // then return the count directly
    return ($related) ? (int) $related->aggregate : 0;
}
```

And in controller

```
$sales = Sale::with('AmountOrder')->get();
```